# Opposite of :contains - Make h2 visible if it does not contain specific text

Tags: jquery, visible

I just asked pretty much the opposite of this question and had great help, so thank you. Challenge now is that the page loads with the heading visible, then it hides it (disappears) so it does not look professional. So I am, using what I learned from your suggestions, trying to do this the opposite way. I have hidden the `<h2>` in CSS and now want the JQuery to make it visible if it **does not** contain the text "All Brands".

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="Block Moveable Panel" id="BrandContent">
  <h2>All Brands</h2>           <--- ALWAYS HIDDEN IN CSS
  <div class="BlockContent">
     BRANDS LISTED HERE...
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few combinations of the below code without success:

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:not(:contains("All Brands")').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

and

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:not(:contains("All Brands")').show();
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions. M

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced. Fix that and I'll bet it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#BrandContent > h2:not(:contains("All Brands"))').show();  
});
```

CSS:

Replace:

```
#BrandContent h2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

To:

```
#BrandContent h2 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: none;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jz2eh/1/)

Comment: Hi @Dh, I can see it works in JSFiddle (thanks!) but it is not operating on my site's page. I will keep trying as there is no other JS on the page targeting the h2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2469528 i just have updated my answer so take a look into that and make sure that you write the code inside the DOM ready.

Comment: Hi @Dh, thanks again but it made no difference. if you can, have a look at http://itoutlet.com.au/brands/ACER.html. The h2 should appear under the free delivery banner... as I said, it has been a long 14 hr day already!

Comment: @user2469528 i can't find free delivery banner in the link that you have given me.

Comment: Hi Dh, the free delivery banner is at the top of second column in the body of the page, underneath the breadcrumbs. It is a png across the page. Underneath this png is where the h2 should appear. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @user2469528 i have found the problem in your css. i just updated my answer. replace your css with mine it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `)` -

```
$('#BrandContent > h2:not(:contains("All Brands"))')
                                                 ^------------
```

Comment: I have just balanced the brackets but it has made no difference? So syntax is correct, so I'll keep fiddling with it. Thanks, too long a day!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $h2 = $('h2');
$h2.not($('.BrandContent > h2:contains("All Brands")')).css('visibility', 'visible')
```

- Select all the `h2`
- Select all `h2` that contains the word `All Brands`
- Using a `not` will give you the h2 that do not contain the words.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3D5ce/22/)**